# Dynamic index path helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to path helpers: *automobile_albums_path* and *community_albums_path*
Album model belongs to polymorphic *owner* and I want to put link to other albums of current album's owner using @album model.

So I want to write something like that:

```
link_to @album.owner.albums
```

But this does not works. I want to avoid using *case* statement to select proper helper. Is there a universal one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def albums_path(owner) # change the name if it will collide with a route helper
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.send "#{owner.class.name.downcase}_albums_path" # add the owner as a second param to 'send' if needed
  end
end
```

Edited!

Comment: Improved version: Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.send "#{owner.class.name.underscore}_albums_path", owner